# Images sometimes don't show up

Tags: javascript, ios, image, web-applications, browser-cache

I have a WebApp that uses the application cache. All the files it uses, including images, are in the manifest file. Sometimes the cached images don't show up when not connected to the internet. Sometimes they do. This mostly happens on IOS.

I also found that certain images that I insert into canvas with drawImage won't show up on first use if I just declare an  file. It will show up on subsequent uses. I finally had to make it a data url.

Any thoughts?